# How to sort specific rows in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a 15x100 matrix and I only want to sort the the first 10 rows in ascending order, what matlab code would do that?

edit: Sort the first 10 rows of each column

Comment: How about `sortrows(x(1:10, :))`?

Comment: That produces a new matrix with only 10 rows, and only sorts by specific columns, from what I have experimented with.

Comment: I just tried that exact line of code and it works perfectly for the first column, but the rest of the columns are still not sorted in ascending order.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
x(1:10, :) = sortrows(x(1:10, :), 1:size(x,2));
```

The second argument of `sortrows` tells it which columns in which order you want to sort. so `1:size(x, 2)` will sort by each column in turn (in ascending order)

If you actually want all the columns to be perfectly sorted (rows 1 to 10) and not keep the row integrity (i.e. each row can no longer be found in the original) then (although this is weird):

```
for col = 1:size(B, 2)
    B(1:10, col) = sort(B(1:10, col));
end
```

Comment: I labeled my matrix B and used B(1:10,:) = sortrows(B(1:10,:),1:size(B,2)) and it is only working on the first column. It does rearrange the other rows but not in ascending order.

Comment: They are sorted each in turn, so first by col 1, then by 2 etc. Are you saying that you want the top 10 rows sorted in each column such that the rows get all muddled up?

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly. Sorry, I was not very clear in my original question. Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: @William Sure thing, if it works please mark it as correct by clicking the outlined tick in the top left of the answer :)

Comment: I will do so immediately after I reach "15 reputation". Thanks again for your help, I greatly appreciated it.

Comment: @William, anyone can accept an answer :) you  only need 15 reputation to vote

Comment: Is it possible to adjust the second argument so that it only sorts rows with column values from 1 - n where n is not the total number of columns in the matrix?

Comment: @BradySheehan yes but you also have to change the column indexing everywhere else i.e.: `x(1:10, 1:n) = sortrows(x(1:10, 1:n), 1:n);`

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, I understand now and this is very useful.